# SQL query to update post_date (one post = one single date & time)

Tags: mysql, date, wp-update-post

I have 120 posts of one category ready for my wordpress blog.
For the moment, posts are drafts and I don't want to schedule them manually.

I want to publish them like this:

- 4 articles each day from the 1st of August 2013
- 1 at 10am / 1 at 2pm / 1 at 5pm / 1 at 8:30pm

What I need is the SQL query to:

- Update date_post for the 120 posts, based on the needs described above
- Change "draft" mode to "pending"
- The publication order is based on the creation date of the posts: the older will be the first published.

I'm lost in the queries and loops.
If someone could help, it would be very very appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Chris

Comment: Any particular articles at those times? Any four or your 120 drafts is ok on any one day?

Comment: any four of the 120 will be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do this with SQL. A relatively simple PHP loop should work.

```
function bulk_schedule_posts_wpse_105834() {
  $args = (
    array(
      'cat' => 1,
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'draft',
      'post_type' => 'post',
    )
  );
  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
  if (!$posts->have_posts()) return false;

  $date = '2013-08-01';
  $times = array(
    '10:00',
    '14:00',
    '17:00',
    '20:30'
  );

  while ($posts->have_posts()) {

    global $post;
    $posts->the_post();

    if (0 !== $posts->current_post && 0 === $posts->current_post%4) {
      $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day',strtotime($date)));
    }

    $thisdate = $date.' '.$times[$posts->current_post%4].':00';
    $date_gmt = get_gmt_from_date($thisdate);
    $post->edit_date = true;
    $post->post_date = $thisdate;
    $post->post_date_gmt = $date_gmt;
    $post->post_status = 'future';

    wp_update_post($post);
  }
}
bulk_schedule_posts_wpse_105834();
```

**Run that function once and then remove it.**

What you are doing is moderately dangerous. Test that thoroughly on dummy data before using it on a live site. I don't think it should actually destroy much data but it could make a big mess.

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. Caveat emptor. No refunds.

Comment: Dear s_ha-dum, 
Thanks a lot for your help, I'll test it on a draft website before on the live stuff. It helps me a lot. I wish you a very pleasant day!

Comment: Firsts tests are OK. Impressive.

Comment: One more point: when you load the site with the script integrated to function.php, it's good to know that the page will be loaded after that every posts status are change. So it can take time depending on the number of drafts.